# HP UX 11.00 Post installation error - FAILURE

Tags: hp-ux

I just installed HP-UX 11.00 on a HP-RP2470 Server.
The installation in general went OK, however near the end I've seen the folowing output on the console:

[image: FAIL]

> Has anybody seen this before? What does this mean? Is this some stupid
>   joke?

Now after the installation everything looks OK and the server is working fine (at least it looks like it is working fine :) ). However this message has brought my attention, and I would still like to know the reason.

The version of the OS is HP-UX 11.00

---
**UPDATE 1440h:**

I did some research and noticed that `/etc/resolv.conf` does not exist.
Any suggestions regarding this file? Perhaps I should create one? If that is the case does anyone know what should I put inside that file?

Comment: Did you do what it said? Did you look for "ERROR" in the log file?

Comment: Yes, `/var/opt/ignite/clients/.../install.log` does not exist. So nothing to search..

Comment: `/var/opt/ignite/local/install.log` - Just an infinite lines of NOTES related to the already existing software. Nothing notable there either.. The file ends with the output on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found that the problem with that error which is not related with the HP-UX, but **it actually related with miss-configuration of the PuTTY window.**

On the background of what was happening is that the HP-UX installation tries to load the `/var/opt/ignite/local/install.log` file. However that file is WAY TOO large (it has more then 6500 lines) for the PuTTY configs and it cannot be displayed properly so the big FAILURE is displaying on the terminal window.

A suggested configuration I recived from a guy on another forum and it is for comfortably administering terminal servers:

> Session ---> Close Window on Exit: Always
>
> Terminal ---> Keyboard ---> The Backspace Key ---> Control-H
>   (was Control-?, the DELETE key)
>
> Window  ---> Columns: 132  Rows: 48
>       (your choice, but 80 is too small for logs and ioscan)
>
> Lines of Scrollback  ---> 50000 **(PuTTY default here is 200 which causes that error)**
>
> Appearance  ---> Cursor appearance: Block
>                              Cursor blinks
>
> Font: Lucida Console, 10-point
>       (or Courier, personal choice, 10 point or adjust to fit screen size)
>
> Font quality: Clear Type
>
> Colours: Font default is gray!! (182, not 255)
>       Set Foreground = 255 255 255
>       Set Background = personal choice
>       (note: Bold = 255, so bold enhancements
>        will be the same)